# Crontab doesn't open for user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, cron

When I am trying to open `crontab` I see the next output:

> ubuntu@macaroon:~$ crontab -l
> crontabs/ubuntu/: fopen: Permission denied

When I add `sudo` it opens fine however, if the jobs don't work there:

```
ubuntu@macaroon:~$ sudo crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# omitted such info
* * * * * /usr/bin/env python3 /home/ubuntu/main.py date >> ~/main_script_cronjob.log
```

***What is missing from this machine? How to fix this behaviour***

Other machines work fine with the regular `crontab` command without `sudo`.

Here I have to do some workaround:

> sudo crontab -u ubuntu -e

Then it opens correct `crontab` for ubuntu user.

**UPDATE:**

Additional information for `crontab` details:

```
ubuntu@macaroon:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/crontab
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root crontab 39568 Mar 23  2022 /usr/bin/crontab
ubuntu@macaroon:~$ sudo namei -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ubuntu
f: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ubuntu
drwxr-xr-x root   root    /
drwxr-xr-x root   root    var
drwxr-xr-x root   root    spool
drwxr-xr-x root   root    cron
drwx-wx--T root   crontab crontabs
-rw------- ubuntu root    ubuntu
```

It is not a Docker container. It is a physical machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crontab` command has lost its permissions. For example, on my (Raspbian) system the permissions include *setgid `crontab`* (the `s` permission bit for the group):

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 30452 Feb 22  2021 /usr/bin/crontab
```

You can confirm this by running `ls -l /usr/bin/crontab` on your problematic system and adding the result to your question. Here's how you'd fix the missing setgid bit:

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,go=rx,g+s /usr/bin/crontab
```

(I prefer symbolic values: User=rwx, Group,Others=rx, Group+setgid. You could equally use the octal `2755`.)

Remember also to tell us if you're trying to run this under Docker, as it often strips permissions by default.

Comment: updated the question with permission details.

Comment: it fixes the issue. BTW could you explain what does `chmod u=rwx,go=rx,g+s` exactly do? I knew something like `chmod +x` -> add execute rights for user/group/others.

Comment: @catch23 answer updated for you. Also read the first few paragraphs of `man 1 chmod`

Answer (score 2):

Working around the problem: You can use systemd-timer.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user
```

The systemd service unit file:

```
cat <<EOF >  ~/.config/systemd/user/myservice.service
[Unit]
Description= description here

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/main.py date >> ~/main_script_cronjob.log'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF
```

Writing the systemd timer unit file.

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.config/systemd/user/myservice.timer
[Unit]
Description="Run service every 1 min"

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:*:00

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF
```

Then enable the service and the timer:

```
systemctl --user start myservice.{service,timer}
```

Comment: More flexible than `crontab` certainly, but considerably more complex to set up (at least, without a helper application)

Comment: very interesting workaround. Played some services in the past with systems. However, this approach to solving this kind of problem is not so trivial to understand.